# fillna for category column with Series input does not work as expected

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a category column which I want to fill with a Series.
I tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['a', 'b'], 'value': ['c', np.nan]})
df['value'] = df['value'].astype("category")
df['value'] = df['value'].cat.add_categories(df['key'].unique())
print(df['value'].cat.categories)
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(df['key'])
print(df)
```

Expected output:

```
Index(['c', 'a', 'b'], dtype='object')
  key value
0   a     c
1   b     b
```

Actual output:

```
Index(['c', 'a', 'b'], dtype='object')
  key value
0   a     a
1   b     b
```

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug, but thankfully the workaround is quite simple. You will have to treat "value" as a string column when filling.

```
df['value'] = pd.Categorical(
    df.value.astype(object).fillna(df.key), categories=df.stack().unique())
df

  key value
0   a     c
1   b     b
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out the workaround for the last 15 minutes to respond it, so thanks bro! :)

Answer (score 2):

From the [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/generated/pandas.core.categorical.Categorical.fillna.html) , Categorical data will accept scalar not series , so you may need to convert it back to series

```
df.value.astype('object').fillna(df.key) # then convert to category again
Out[248]: 
0    c
1    b
Name: value, dtype: object
```

> value : scalar Value to use to fill holes (e.g. 0)

Comment: Nice, so this is the reason.

Comment: However, I feel like passing a Series should throw an error rather than silently give the wrong answer. Perhaps there is room for improvement in the API.

Comment: @coldspeed Yes you are right man , I have the same idea like you : it is better return a error or even a warning , rather then the wrong output